# ¿Cómo instalar libapache2-mod-wsgi en OpenSuse SLE sp2?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, servidor

He intentado ejecutar estas dos sentencias de Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

En OpenSuse:

```
$ sudo zypper update
$ sudo zypper install apache2
$ sudo zypper install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Pero al ejecutar la última linea obtengo esto:

```
Refreshing service 'SMT-http_smt-ec2_susecloud_net'.
Refreshing service 'cloud_update'.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libapache2-mod-wsgi' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'libapache2-mod-wsgi' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a instalar con:

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Apache:Modules/SLE_12_SP2/Apache:Modules.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install apache2-mod_wsgi
```